# How to check if the text entered is a path with javafx?

Tags: javafx, path

i'm trying to build an app based on paths so what i want to ask is how to check the path/directory if it's in the correct form. For example if the user entered a text in the textfield after clicking a button it should verify that is a path not anything (path in the correct form) so how can i check that? and thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean correct path in the current OS format, or existing path (file or directory) on the current machine?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) class and [Path Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html).